# servlet not redirecting to a html page with dynamic address

Tags: html, servlets

I wrote a dynamic webproject to convert the xml page to html page, so that it can be deployed on the tomcat server and so it is converting the xml pages to html pages sucessfully, but depending on the location where the tomcat is deployed on the computer it creates the html file(output.html) in the same folder, so i need to provide a button in the html page to redirect to the html page created by my project so i used following code to redirect to the output.html page.(In the html page i created a form element and a button, on clicking that button the servlet should redirect to output.html page)

```
 String outputhtml=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("output.html");
 ServletContext sc1 = this.getServletContext();
 RequestDispatcher rd = sc1.getRequestDispatcher(outputhtml);
 rd.include(request, response);
```

it did not worked so i used

```
 response.setContentType("text/html");
 String site = new String(outputhtml);
 response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
 response.setHeader("Location", site);
```

Even this did not work for me
please give a solution to solve this problem.

Comment: where is the output.html saved ? In which folder?

Comment: have you tried using sendRedirect()